# Best approach to query an Optional with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, spring-jdbc

Well, yes, I want to query an Optional result, consider given SQL:

```sql
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz = 123
LIMIT 1
```

This query returns either a row with some value, say some String, or no rows at all.

With Spring JDBC, as we know, I can't just use `queryForObject` as it throws on empty result. The remaining methods I can use is `query`, `queryForList` and `queryForStream`. And here's my question:

Which of these solutions is the best in terms of performance?

```java
// 1:
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, i) -> rs.getString(0)).stream().findAny();

// 2:
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class).stream().findAny();

// 1.1, 2.1, considering qres is "query result"

for (var res : qres) {
  return Optional.of(res);
}
return Optional.empty();

// 1.2, 2.2
return qres.size() == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(qres.get(0));

// 3:
try(var stream = jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(sql, (rs, i) -> rs.getString(0))) {
  return stream.findAny();
}
```

Is there any "idiomatic" way to do so I didn't found?

If you use not the most performant solution, tell, if there's any trade off you've taken in account?

References to any related articles are very appreciated.

---

P.S. If there's any other ways which I don't remember at a time, please provide them.

P.P.S. I've just realised that if `foo` is nullable, then we have inconsistency in result, as Optional.empty may mean "no rows" and "one row with null". However, let's assume `foo` is non-null this time. But if you have any solution to this, please put it in comments.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a method `Optional<T> doMyQuery(sql)` where you want a to return: (a) the query result (as a `T`) if the query returned a row, or (b) an empty optional if the query returned no rows?  I don't think you'll find any way is more "idiomatic" than any other (for some value of "idiomatic" :-).  Distinguishing no-rows from 1-row-null will require a sentinel instance of `T`.

Comment: The answer to this will be quite subjective, there's not really a right or wrong way to go about it. My question is though is the use of an `Optional` strictly necessary? In our own implementation we have a subclass of `JdbcTemplate` with `queryForObject` method that returns `null` if it doesn't find anything.

Comment: I'm really sorry for unclearness in this question, but there's nothing subjective. What I want is to collect as more approaches as possible and do some research in their performance. So, the true question must be "Which of these solutions is the best in terms of performance? If you use not the most performant solution, tell, if there's any trade off you've taken in account". References to acticles is also appreciated. I'll update the question btw.

Comment: @mohammedkhan Your approach with custom `queryForObject` is awesome! I'm definitely going to look into it